# Total SUM of a column within a Tablerow inside another Tablerow, for only the set of data that fits between 2 Date variables and another variable (0)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying again to post, but this time in a condensed format.

As the title says, trying to Total SUM of a column within a Tablerow inside another Tablerow. Where it should take the dates that range from 'Service_Agreements.sa_start_date' to the date in 'Service_Agreements.sa_end_date' WHERE Service_Agreements.sa_closed == 0 (and the rest are ignored of course).

Managed to do this:

```
                <?php
            // Take total hours of casenotes for each Service Type under its Service Group separately. But it totals the entire Service Type. I want to only total certain things. Just need to be able to take the last 3 variables into consideration (sa_start_date, sa_end_date and sa_closed == 0) 

                $sqltot = "SELECT SUM(Casenotes.cn_hours) AS total_hours FROM Casenotes, Service_Agreements 
                WHERE Casenotes.part_id = :partid AND Casenotes.serv_group = :groupid AND Casenotes.cn_group = :cngroupid
                AND Service_Agreements.participant_id = :sapartid AND Service_Agreements.serv_group = :sagroupid 
                AND Service_Agreements.cn_group = :sacngroupid AND Service_Agreements.sa_closed = -0";

                $st = $pdo->prepare($sqltot);

                $st->bindvalue(':partid', $partid);                 
                $st->bindvalue(':groupid', $grp['serv_group']);
                $st->bindvalue(':cngroupid', $cngroupid);
                $st->bindvalue(':sapartid', $partid);
                $st->bindvalue(':sagroupid', $grp['serv_group']);
                $st->bindvalue(':sacngroupid', $cngroupid);

                $st->execute();
                
                
                foreach($st as $rowst) {
                    echo $rowst['total_hours'];
                }

            ?>
```

The table in question (highlighted is the range date example. Where in the "Total Hours: 48", I want it to only show those dates in range, which should result to: "Total Hours: 6.5".

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POJH0.png)

Here is a link to an SQL Fiddle for your convenience:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8cc5f

I really am struggling with is writing this psuedocode in PHP format: BUT COUNT ONLY THE Casenotes.cn_hours IF THEY ARE BETWEEN THESE DATES FROM Service_Agreements.sa_start_date AND Service_Agreements.sa_end_date AND ALSO ONLY IF IT IS Service_Agreemetns.sa_closed == 0.

That is all I want to write in PHP but I just do not know what I am doing wrong and no matter how I try I either end up with errors OR there is no output.

Any help will be great, thank you!

Comment: your table fields are a bit cryptic. Could you describe the relationship between case notes and service agreements? I see serv_group as a common field, but do they have a foreign key relationship?

Comment: Yes, the Service_Agreements have these as foreign keys: user_id, participant_id, service_id.